# Similarities between HTML class and OO class

Tags: css, html

I understand the title is a bit misleading, but I come from an Object-Oriented background, and I've recently began a shift towards web development. I've only got a basic grasp of HTML, and been learning and messing around with CSS, but there are some parts of it that are a bit confusing, and I'm trying to get it into terms I can understand.

My CSS:

```
.Person .span4 p
{
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-right:10px;
     margin-top:10px;
}
```

From what I can understand, this means that any p tag that is inside a container, like  with the class of "span4", which is in turn inside another container that has class="Person" will be formatted with the specifications listed above. 
In other words person.span4.p.format(String[] formatArgs), where the formatArgs are the margin-left, right, and top.

The Question: Is this an appropriate way to look at it?

I know it might be comparing apples to oranges, but I'd like to get an opinion before I go running with some conclusion that could be very wrong, and an actual explanation on how these work.

Comment: you should also check out something like sass (http://sass-lang.com/) which makes css a bit more object-oriented-like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question about `.Person .span4 p` is correct, that will style a `p` element that's a descendant of an element with a `span4` class that's a descendant of an element with a `Person` class.

However I wouldn't try to interpret classes in HTML as similar in any way to OO classes. They're completely different concepts, and I think that'll just end up confusing things.

Classes can be assigned to HTML elements using the class attribute (`class="span4"`), and these can then be used in CSS or JavaScript to apply additional styling or behaviours to those elements. Think of giving an element a class as tagging it with a particular keyword, so it can be easily targeted later. Elements can also be assigned multiple classes by separating them with a space, eg. `class="span4 box"`.

In addition, `.Person .span4 p` isn't actually a "class", it's a selector. The `.span4` syntax is called a class selector, the `p` is an element selector, and using a space between two selectors creates a descendant selector. Additionally `#myId` is an ID selector, and there are [plenty of other types of selector as well](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref).

I'd recommend [this guide](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/selectors/) as a good way to get up to speed on the correct terminology.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really cleared that up for me.